# How to snap app programmatically in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

how can I programmatically set a windows 8 application to snapped view? Also, what happens if the screen resolution is 1024 where snap is not allowed? Will an exception occur when calling this function?

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question - how can I programmatically set a windows 8 application to snapped view?

Seems it is not possible.  Please refer following link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/263b39dd-89d4-4f39-96dc-596a500fa10a