# Force WinRT app to snapped view

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

For one of my apps I'd like to send the app to snapped view after tapping a button. As far as I know there's no public API available to send a running application to snapped view. Did anyone find a workaround to do this?

Somehow it should be possible since you're able to do it in Windows 8 itself, and snap one of the running apps.

[image]

Update: Being able to trigger a Win+. might do the same trick, but the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) API isn't available in WinRT either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to snap app programmatically in windows 8 (javascript)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668721/how-to-snap-app-programmatically-in-windows-8-javascript)

Comment: From the link: "No there are no APIs for that.  It is a user initiated action."  This is applicable to ALL languages.

Comment: Found a workaround to fire Win+. to send the app to snapped, works like a charm. Gonna cook up a blog post on it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 has a [ApplicationView.TryResizeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview) method

So... to summarize the interesting WinRT journey:

#### **Windows 8**

Has a a 'Snapped' mode that a only a user can initiate. the developer can try to unsnap with the TryUnsnap method

#### **Windows 8.1**

Does not have Snapped mode, and TryUnsnap is deprecated. The dev can still listen for window size changes and know if the app view is in a smaller size as before.

#### **Windows 10**

Introduced the [ApplicationView.TryResizeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview) method, where the dev can *try* to resize. Window size changed event is still there.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new size(width, height)));
```

Comment: Nice summary Iris. 
You used to be able to trick it into snapped in 8 with triggering a key combination (I never came to write that post), but that broke in 8.1 as well.

Comment: I totally missed that, I'm surprised that was possible considering the sandboxing.I took a look at the supported Win32 and COM APIs for 8.1 and10 and couldn't see anything useful (in terms of key input) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to force an application into snapped mode - it has to be a user initiated action.

An application can request to be *unsnapped* through:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryUnsnap();
```

Which tries to push the app into fill mode.

Comment: Just to note, the TryUnsnap API is deprecated in Windows 8.1 because there's a variable sizing model now.

Comment: Indeed; sadly theres no replacement.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to simulate `W+KeyUp` with javascript to unsnap the app