# Run metro app in snapped state from another metro app

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I would like to run metro application in snapped state with path and parameter from another Metro (Windows RT) application (Cordova platform). Desired state is that both applications will occuppy one half of the screen. Javascript language is preferred. Is this possible, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is : NO You can't !!

Please nav to this question to get more details : 
[Force WinRT app to snapped view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907058/force-winrt-app-to-snapped-view)
..

Comment: But when I open bingmaps from URI, they open just like I want the second appplication to be opened (half of the screen). So this feature is reserved only to bingmaps?